# How edit .org file in text mode

Tags: org-mode

Is there any way to temporarily change the mode of org files to be able to edit them as ordinary text files?

Comment: Do `M-x text-mode` and then when you're done do `M-x org-mode`.

Comment: So simple when you know how! Many thanks.

Comment: Also, may be you just need `visible-mode`.

Comment: To expand on @crocefisso comment: enabling this mode, according to describe-function will "Toggle making all invisible text temporarily visible". First thing you may notice is that org-mode styling of text (such as making words bold by putting asterisks around them or italicizing by putting a word between slashes) will change so that you can see the literal characters '*', '/' and so on around the words (they are now visible). Perhaps this is what made the OP ask the question.

Comment: Thank you @Alex for this explanation which expresses flawlessly what I had in mind.

Comment: @Alex - that is exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: How would I bind a key to toggle between org-mode and test-mode?